# Only input boxes of bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet, frontend

I am currently building a site and I wanted to style my input boxes like bootstrap ones, however I don't want to use other features provided by bootstrap. Could someone recommend me how I could just export that feature and include in my CSS. There maybe some JavaScript too I believe.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize and select only the items that you want to.

Comment: @freestock.tk Great thanks. I will have this a go

Comment: Be aware some items only fully works while combined with another items. e.g.: 'alerts' (the box alert itself) and 'alert dismissal' (the jquery function to close the box);

Answer (score 6):

There is no related on javascript at all when comes input field.

You can build input field like bootstrap exactly.

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="text" class="bootstrap">
```

**css**

```
.bootstrap{
  width:250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline:none;
  padding: 6px;
}

.bootstrap:focus{
  border:1px solid #56b4ef;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #c8def0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/7u29pvab/)

Comment: Thanks, as you can tell front-end is my down point. I would have this a go, I am also looking into buttons and dropdowns, I know it is a pain to make all look the same in different browsers, perhaps you can help me further

Comment: Sure :D just let me know when you had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any other aspect of Bootstrap. You only use what you want by adding calls to bootstrap like this,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

the class="form-control" calls the bootstrap css. You can have the following on the same page and it will display without inheriting the Bootstrap styling,

```
<input type="text">
```

You could search the Bootstrap css file for .form-control and copy/past that specific css element into your own style sheet if you didn't want to use the entire bootstrap file.

Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I may give this a go, as I am really looking for how to style buttons, dropdowns and make sure they are same in most browsers